# wrong 2nd argument type. required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The error im getting is:
Wrong 2nd arguement type. found: 'com.example.appname.MainmenuFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
By the way I know a similar question has been asked but that case is slightly different because this code is written in MainmenuActivity which is an activity not a fragment and MainmenuFragment is a fragment as the name implies. It worked this morning. I've been exploring quite a lot today but ended up having this unusual error. Here is the code in which I am getting the error:

```
public class MainmenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_mainmenu:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainmenuFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
}
return false;
};

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainmenuFragment()).commit();

    }}
```

the line

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainmenuFragment()).commit();
```

and

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainmenuFragment()).commit();
```

is where I am getting the error. To be honest if I try using other fragment files instead of Mainmenu_Fragment it works fine wierdly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your `MainmenuFragment`

Comment: thats not thte case because i am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment in my MainmenuFragment.

Comment: actually you were kind of right. I extended android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it did help you :)! Sorry that I hadn't answered your comment yesterday but I hadn't had any clue about where the issue could be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because of `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Try changing it to `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried changing it, it solved the issue but the other two fragments that I have under the 'MainmenuFragment()).commit' that I have not shown in the code above gets the error: 'Required: android.app.Fragment'.